# Open DTE solution from another program (not add-in)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, extension-methods, solution, envdte

Is it possible to modify a solution, and use envdte tools, from a command-line project ?

I have an add-in that modifies a solution. But... the changes are required for over a hundred projects... So I'd like to make a c# program that has the same logic, only it iterates through all solution files.

The add-in starts with

```
EnvDTE.Solution solution = (EnvDTE.Solution)application.Solution;
```

where `DTE2 application` is passed from the add-in...

How can I get the same solution, which then I query for projects...
From a separate program, that will only know the solutionPath ?

Is it possible to open the solution, process it, and close it - to move on to the next solution ?

Microsoft gives this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.open(v=vs.100).aspx

But I don't know what dte is in the context...

Thank you...

VS 2010

**edit:** I did what the answer below suggests. 
Slightly modified, using the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.100).aspx

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need to activate an instance using the COM CLSID for Visual Studio. An example is below. It actually creates a solution and adds two projects to it but the same initialization applies when opening an existing solution.

A couple of caveats:

1. Mind the COM threading model. The code created from the console app template is sufficient:

   ```
   [STAThread]
   static void Main()
   ```
2. If you have a powerful VS extension like ReSharper installed, you might be better off suspending it if you don't need it for the VS automation. ReSharper had VS commands that control it.

   ```
       Console.WriteLine("Opening Visual Studio");
       var dte = (DTE)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0",true),true);

       Console.WriteLine("Suspending Resharper");
       dte.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper_Suspend");

       Console.WriteLine("Working with {0}, {1} edition", dte.FullName, dte.Edition);
       dte.SuppressUI = true;
       dte.UserControl = false;

       foreach (var solution in mySolutionInfoList)
       {
           try
           {                    
               dte.Solution.Create(solution.directory, solution.name);                    
               dte.Solution.AddFromTemplate(csharpTemplatePath, solution.directory + "ClassLibrary1", "ClassLibrary1");
               dte.Solution.AddFromTemplate(vcTemplatePath, solution.directory + "Win32Dll", "Win32Dll");
               Directory.CreateDirectory(solution.directory); // ensure directory exists. Otherwise, user will be asked for save location, regardless of SupressUI value
               dte.Solution.Close(true); 
               Console.WriteLine();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
           }
       }

       Console.WriteLine("Resuming Resharper");
       dte.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper_Resume");

       try
       {
           dte.Quit();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
       }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I will try, this looks great. I don't have ReSharper, I do have VisualHG that has interfered with removing projects from current solution... I'm hoping that it may not from command line.