# Scripting EF Add-Migration into an automated build task

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, build-automation, entity-framework-migrations

I have all my ef code first migrations in a separate assembly called `Migrations`

From the package manager console I type `Add-Migration xyz` which scaffolds up a migration

Is it possible to do this from outside of visual studio?  I'm using rake scripts to do lots of automation for my build but this is one part that I've not quite got yet.  The goal here would be to do the following

`rake db:add_migration "xyz"`

This would run some command and add the migration to the specified project.  That's the only bit I've not been able to figure out how to automate yet!  I'd probably build in other tasks along with this like dropping and creating the database and the getting the migration out to a script so it could be run under my roundhouse migrations.

Related material

```
Add-Migration [-Name] <String> [-Force]
[-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>]
[-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] [-ConnectionStringName <String>]
[-IgnoreChanges] [<CommonParameters>]
```

[Command Reference](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Add-Migration)

I can see that EF is installed to the packages folder from nuget

```
packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools
```

And I can see in the file `EntityFramework.psm1`

```
function Add-Migration
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ConnectionStringName')]
    param (
        [parameter(Position = 0,
....
}
```

But I'm not sure how to execute it from the command line.  I've tried

```
..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools>powershell EntityFramework.psm1 Add-Migration
```

but this results in an error

```
The term 'EntityFramework.psm1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:21
    + EntityFramework.psm1 <<<<  Add-Migration
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (EntityFramework.psm1:String) [],
                              CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Why not just use automatic migrations?

Comment: No audit trail if you do it this way.

Comment: Well... You can always look at the __MigrationHistory table if you want an audit trail.

Comment: I export the migrations to SQL files because I want the traceability.  I run the migrations from `RoundHouse` as it's far more fully featured than `migrate.exe`

Comment: You can use the provided migrate.exe it is in the installed Nuget package. See usage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618307(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking in `EntityFramework.psm1` it is merely a scripting facade for the EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll. The actual add-migrations functionality is implemented in the `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand` class in that assembly.

Looking at the source, it gets the currently active  project (I assume that's the project that's selected in the powershell console)  through this line:

```
get { return (Project)_domain.GetData("project"); }
```

`Project` is `EnvDTE.Project` which (if I google correctly) is a way to interface with the IDE. Some further source reading reveals that files are added to the project by interfacing with the IDE.

<strike>To me it looks like the scaffolding code is too heavily integrated with the Visual Studio to be possible to run outside of Visual Studio as part of a command line build.</strike>

#### Edit

I'm getting back to this and figured out that it might be possible. There's another SO question that describes how to use EnvDTE outside of visual studio, e.g. from command line apps:

[Open DTE solution from another program (not add-in)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994899/open-dte-solution-from-another-program-not-add-in)

So it might indeed be possible to write an own .exe wrapper around the `EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll` if the app domain is prepared with the proper EnvDTE objects before calling the `AddMigrationCommand` class. To do that you would have to analyze the Entity Framework source code to know how to fool the scaffolding code to beleive it runs inside of Visual Studio.

So, in the end: It might be possible - but it will be a non trivial project to write your own tool for it.

Comment: @Neil: Looked a bit more into it. I think that I was wrong - it might be possible (although non-trivial).

Comment: Excellent, I'll do a little console app and see if I can get the functionality in the Dlls to play.

Comment: I had a quick shot this afternoon but it really seems like it is a bit beyond me at the moment.  I'm sure given a week or so I could muddle my way through but doesn't seem like a good use of time unfortunately.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 4):

The EF Powershell commands must be run from within Visual Studio in order to work. From command line, you can use [migrate.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307), but it does not support adding new migrations.

Comment: Are you certain of this? Any link or ref to back this up?

Comment: We do have a few items on our codeplex site tracking the general improvement of our migrate.exe experience. Feel free to join in the conversation there if you're interested in generating migrations from command line. (example: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/315)

Comment: Also, as per Anders Abel's answer above, it may be possible to wrap/mock the VS DTE APIs, but we've never tried it. If you get it working, write-up how you did it and let us know!

Comment: That's good to know, I'll maybe make a feature request. I'll see how I get on with the console app over the next week. I'd have to start a blog to write it up though. I like EF but it could be a bit easier to integrate into automated builds and deployments

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (automate add-migration) and came up with the solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586367/how-to-automate-package-manager-console-in-visual-studio-2013/20651122#20651122).

You can create a console app that opens up a headless visual studio instance to get a project reference.  With the project reference, you can call directly into the EntityFramework code (not through the Powershell) to trigger a migration and get the code back.

Once you have the code, you can send it where ever you want (like into a file that is added to the project.